# Running additional code with auto property setter

Tags: c#, properties, getter-setter

Is it possible to run additional code in the setter, only using [auto implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)? I.e. something like this, just using auto properties:

```
// I Would like to get rid of this...
int privateField 

// ...and only have this
public int PrivateField 
{
    get { return privateField; }
    set
    {
        privateField = value;
        functionDependingOnSetter(value);
    }
}
```

(in case it is not clear, I want the function `functionDependingOnSetter()` to run, whenever the property setter is called).

Comment: That is what your code will do :)

Comment: I know, it works, but I want to use auto properties, to avoid the private field. If possible...

Comment: `public int PrivateField { get; set; };` is just the shorthand of your code, minus `functionDependingOnSetter()` . If you want to implement a function while setting a property value, you gotta follow the same as in your question

Comment: @Nobody so what you are saying is, that my example is the shortest (and easiest) way to do this? I.e. auto implemented properties are not an option...

Comment: As i said  `{ get; set; }` would just let you skip the private field, but to do a function around the `set` value you would have to carry this private field and write those extra steps just as you have done in the question. no other way. If there is no method to be called while `set` or `get` operations, this `public int PrivateField { get; set; };` would be enough

Comment: Just out of curiosity, may i ask this: Do you actually know what happens when u use _auto implemented properties_?

Comment: @Nobody it is my understanding, that the private field is created in the hidden. And that `get` and `set` are then automatically implemented in the simplest possible way. What I was curious about was, if there was some way to add additional functionally to this automatic implementation.

Comment: yes your understanding is correct, while using _auto implemented properties_ the compiler creates a backing field by itself. But it **doesn't know** that _you_ want to implement a function in-between the `set` operation. `{get; set;}` is just a syntactical sugar or shorthand for what you have done. To implement a function you would have to do the same process as in your question unless and until a new C# version with this functionality u seek is released :)